# How was this geometric product series simplified?

Tags: recurrence-relations, products

I feel very strange asking this but  [here is a problem I have from a textbook of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX5dR.jpg). Simply put, I do not understand how (a_(t-1)*a_(t-2)…a_1) became the pi-product of a_i/a_o.

As a result, I dont [understand how he got to this definition for a difference equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iap7o.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly expanding out the notation?

Comment: I tried to expand and I feel I am missing some core concepts of pi-product because it wasnt obvious to me what I was missing

Comment: Hoy et al. (2005) - Mathematics for Economists https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Economics-MIT-Press-Michael/dp/0262015072

Comment: See my updated answer.  The error has been corrected in the fourth edition.

Comment: Oh wow, so it is a typo!!!! I feel so relieved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{t-1} \frac{a_i}{a_0} \not= \frac{1}{a_0} \prod_{i=0}^{t-1} a_i = \frac{1}{a_0} a_0 \cdots a_{t-1} = a_1 \cdots a_{t-1}$$
Correct notation is:
$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{t-1} a_i}{a_0} = a_1 \cdots a_{t-1}$$

Note that it is corrected in the [fourth edition of the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=prZNEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA757&lpg=PA757&dq=%22a%20more%20compact%20way%20of%20expressing%20this%20solution%20is%22&source=bl&ots=scigKC6jDB&sig=ACfU3U2W5YBqucnP-VqnhIpDV0Q2SW0I1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0v8bfppr4AhX1RTABHcI0DN4Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20more%20compact%20way%20of%20expressing%20this%20solution%20is%22&f=false).

More generally:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{t-1} k\cdot a_i = k^t \prod_{i=0}^{t-1} a_i$$
Contrast with sums:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} k\cdot a_i = k \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} a_i$$

Answer (score 0):

The book seems to be wrong, unless there's some hidden assumption not shown in your picture. For $t = 4$, the first line gives

$$
y_4 = (a_3a_2a_1a_0)y_0 + (a_3a_2a_1)b_0 + (a_3a_2)b_1 + (a_3)b_2 + b_3
$$

While the second line gives

$$\begin{align*}
y_4 &= (a_3a_2a_1a_0)y_0 + b_0\left(\frac{a_3a_2a_1a_0}{a_0^4}\right) + b_1\left(\frac{a_3a_2a_1}{a_1^3}\right) + b_2\left(\frac{a_3a_2}{a_2^2}\right) + b_3\left(\frac{a_3}{a_3}\right) \\
&= (a_3a_2a_1a_0)y_0 + \frac{a_3a_2a_1}{a_0^3}\cdot b_0 + \frac{a_3a_2}{a_1^2}\cdot b_1 + \frac{a_3}{a_2}\cdot b_2 + b_3
\end{align*}$$